# R weighted average

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm totaly new to R and to be honest, I just actually need to incorporate one calculation into my azure machine learning model.

I have data such as:

```
ApplicationID,ApplicationDate,ClientAgeToApplicationDate,RequiredLoanDuration,WeekOfYear,JobName,DistrictName,RiskScore
68679,16.02.2012 0:00:00,55.00000000,12,8,Unknown,Česká Lípa,0
68681,15.02.2012 0:00:00,38.00000000,48,8,Unknown,Olomouc,0
68682,08.02.2012 0:00:00,29.00000000,36,7,Unknown,Třebíč,0
68684,18.02.2012 0:00:00,24.00000000,30,8,Unknown,Uherské Hradiště,4
68687,17.02.2012 0:00:00,32.00000000,24,8,Unknown,Blansko,4
```

and I want to make least ApplicationDates more relevant.

I'm using multi-class NN and have tried:

```
# Sample operation
data.set = rbind(dataset1);

# Take last 1/3 of a year as the most relevant
library(dplyr)
grouped <- data.set %>% group_by(ClientAgeToApplicationDate, RequiredLoanDuration, WeekOfYear, JobName, DistrictName) %>% filter(as.numeric(Sys.Date() - 'ApplicationDate', units="days") <= 120) %>% summarise(mean(RiskScore))
data.set <- data.set %>% left_join(grouped)

# You'll see this output in the R Device port.
# It'll have your stdout, stderr and PNG graphics device(s).
plot(data.set);
```

Help would be aprreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your desired output? Your code looks like it works to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but a weighted average is easy: `?weighted.mean`

Comment: When ran, I'm getting this error: "non-numeric argument to binary operator". It's cause by the as.numeric function, but I don't see a reason why.

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting a character string from Sys.Date()